# Select custom 'down' icon and use of :after

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation 4 and I am trying to override the standard '-webkit-appearance: menu-list;' which I can turn off but I can't get it to allow for me to override the icon.  I attempted to try :after and that doesn't work (I found why in another post).  I'm wondering, is there a way (other than jquery) to use css to replace the select menu icon?

If I have to use jquery that's fine but I'd rather be using css if possible.